# Trying to solve: Show that n does not divide 3^n - 2^n for n greater than or equal to 2.

Tags: nt.number-theory

Clearly true if n is a multiple of 2 or 3. Also, you can show it's true for n prime using Fermat's little theorem. You can also show that if n divides 3{a+b} - 2^{a+b} and n divides 3^a - 2^a then n divides 3^b - 2^b.

Not sure where to go from there though, or if I should be trying something completely different...

Comment: This shows every sign of being homework.  Note, for example, the imperative voice.  Voting, therefore, to close. 

Comment: This isn't homework...

Comment: Sorry, just read the FAQ. This clearly isn't a research question. I guess stackexchange would have been better. Anyway, I am grateful for Gjergji's help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take $p$ to be the smallest prime divisor of $n$. You have that $p$ divides $3^{p-1}-2^{p-1}$ and also $3^n-2^n$. So $p$ divides $3^{\operatorname{gcd}(p-1,n)}-2^{\operatorname{gcd}(p-1,n)}$. However it is easy to see that this gcd must equal $1$, so $p$ divides $3-2$, and we obtain the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I correct my answer. We have $3^n -2^n\equiv 1 \mod p$ for the smallest prime divisor $p$ of $n$.
The proof is the same as the one by Gjergji Zaimi. Write  $n=p^k\ell$ and use Fermat's little theorem repeatedly:
$$
3^n-2^n\equiv 3^{\ell}-2^{\ell}\equiv 3^{(p-1,\ell)}-2^{(p-1,\ell)}\equiv 1\mod p,
$$
since $(p-1,\ell)=1$, because every prime divisor of $\ell$ is bigger than $p-1$.

Comment: $(3^6-2^6) \mod 6 = 5$

Comment: That argument works, but with mod $p$, where $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $n$
